# Problema com drag and drop no JS

Tags: javascript, html

Eu uso o seguinte código pra fazer mover divs (não sei se isso se chama drag and drop)

```
function Drag(Janela){
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  Janela = document.getElementById(Janela);
  document.onmousedown = DragMouseDown;
  function DragMouseDown(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmousemove = ElementDrag;
    document.onmouseup = CloseDragElement;
  }
  function ElementDrag(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    Janela.style.top = (Janela.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    Janela.style.left = (Janela.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }
  function CloseDragElement(){
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

O problema é que quando uma div é movida, não consigo digitar nos inputs dentro dele

Comment: Não vejo nada no teu código que possa motivar o problema que descreves... podes criar um exemplo que mostra isso a acontecer?

Comment: `document.onmouseup = null;` é agressivo para o browser, diria mesmo errado. Não te aparecem erros na consola?

Comment: nenhum erro no console....

Comment: input com o tipo number, por exemplo, clico nas setinas pra aumentar ou diminuar e nada acontece...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema. Se eu tirar o onmousedown do documento e passar para a barra de título da janela, resolve!

```
function Drag(Janela, Bar){
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  Janela = document.getElementById(Janela);
  Bar.onmousedown = DragMouseDown;
  function DragMouseDown(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmousemove = ElementDrag;
    document.onmouseup = CloseDragElement;
  }
  function ElementDrag(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    Janela.style.top = (Janela.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    Janela.style.left = (Janela.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }
  function CloseDragElement(){
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```